# adding a tag when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I need a script when the selected text is surrounded by tags after clicking on the button. For example, there was the text

> This is my text, I love read

I selected "my text" and then clicked on the button, and this text becomes surrounded by tags, for example

> This is < myTag >my text< /myTag >, I love read

The principle of operation is the same as that of text editors, when you can change fonts and style of the text, but I need to surround the text with my tag. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use selectionStart, selectionEnd properties of the textarea.

```js
function getSel(){
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    txtarea.value =
        txtarea.value.substring(0, start) + 
        '<mytag>' + txtarea.value.substring(start, finish) + '</mytag>' +
        txtarea.value.substring(finish);
}
```